# jQuery not works on <li> elements, but not <a> elements

Tags: jquery, element

I have some jQuery code that runs when an item with a certain ID is clicked on. It's working when the ID is part of an `<li>` element, but not when it's in an `<a>` element. Why would this be? I'd like to use an  as it allows me to achieve some stuff if the user has JavaScript turned off.

**EDIT:** Neither preventdefault or return false seem to make any difference.

HTML and Code below:

```
<li><a id="OfficeNav-Bath" class="first" href="#bath">Bath</a></li>
```

**EDIT:** It works if there's no HREF specified in the `<a>` element.

```
$(function() {
    $("#OfficeNav-Bath").click(function(){
        $('.office').removeClass('visible');
    });             
});
```

Any idea why this would be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give us the html code also?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle that reproduces this error?

Comment: If you have more than one `a` element you should give separate ids for each other

Comment: As the href is a hashtag it has nothing to do with `prevenDefault()` as the answers say.

Comment: Hi @Cristy - indeed, those solutions aren't working; do you know what might?

Comment: @MateiMihai, yes, all the links have seperate IDs, just only showing one here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you are not preventing the default event when using with `<a>` tags, so try doing:

```
$(function() {
   $("#OfficeNav-Bath").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('.office').removeClass('visible');
   });           
});
```

Comment: Hi - that's not working I'm afraid; is this as Cristy suggest because the HREF is a hashtag rather than a full URL?

Comment: The eventual error turned out to be something else, but I also needed to include this, so choosing it as an answer to a question I didn't know I needed to ask!

Answer (score 1):

You must add to click event a simple thing:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Better is often to use e.preventDefault(); instead of return false; as preventDefault() keep bubbling

Answer (score 1):

When an anchor element is clicked the browser tries to navigate to the URL to which the anchor's `href` attribute points.

It's possible to override this behaviour using the method `preventDefault` on the `event` object that the event handler receives as paramenter.

```
$("#OfficeNav-Bath").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```