# # (hash) characters in a HREF stops preventDefault from working

Tags: jquery, href, preventdefault

I previously posted a question where my jQuery wasn't working when a HREF was specified in a link ([original question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257054/jquery-not-works-on-li-elements-but-not-a-elements)).

The most common suggested answer was to use preventDefault, but for some reason, this doesn't work if there's a hash/anchor in the HREF; so for example if the URL is "http://www.google.com", it prevents the default behaviour and runs the jQuery as expected, but if it's "http://www.google.co.uk#whatever", it ignores the preventDefault and follows the link.

The link I'm using has a target (indeed, is only a target within the same page). Is there a workaround for this quirky behaviour?

**HTML**

```
<li><a id="OfficeNav-Bath" class="first" href="#bath" >Bath</a></li>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script> <!--Offices jquery -->
        $(function() {$("#OfficeNav-Bath").click(function(e){e.preventDefault(); $('.office').removeClass('visible');});});
</script>
```

Comment: Using jsFiddle `#` within a href has no impact and `event.PreventDefault()` is working as expected. See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MPTDk/)

Comment: have you tried to put the line 'return false;' at the end of your click-event-function?

Comment: @algorhythm, yes, is similarly affected I'm afraid.

Comment: @OliJeffery: `return false` is equal to `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`, so if the issue is with preventing default actions then it makes sense that `return false` does not make a difference. `PreventDefault` seems to work as expected though in latest FF, Chrome and IE9. Are you running a specific version of jQuery and in a specific browser? Could you create a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any information on the exact version of jquery you are using having a `#` in the `href` seems to be no issue using jQuery 1.8.2.

Using jsFiddle `#` within a href has no impact and `event.PreventDefault()` is working as expected.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MPTDk/) - `event.PreventDefault()` and `#` in `href`

Code from DEMO above is below in-case of link-rot.

HTML:

```
<a id="OfficeNav-Bath" class="first" href="http://www.google.com#whatever" >click me</a>
```

Script:

```
$("#OfficeNav-Bath").on("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("Prevent Default Works");
})
```

Comment: @algorhythm: The fiddle you linked also works as expected in Chrome , FF and IE 9. Which browser do you test it in where it does not work in?

Comment: The error was in the code I was trying to run; using your jFiddle examples I got the version working. It seems to have been including $(function() { at the start that messed things up.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl why asking me? I have no prob with the code above

Comment: @algorhythm: Ah, I see. I thought you intended to link the fiddle as an example of where the code is **not** working, that is why I asked why you see it not working. My apologies for the mix-up. I misinterpreted the comment.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a problem with this code, the problem should be elsewhere.

Check it out:

- http://jsbin.com/ozoyab/1/edit
- http://jsbin.com/ozoyab/1/

with target:

- http://jsbin.com/ozoyab/2/edit
- http://jsbin.com/ozoyab/2/

Answer (score 1):

I think what youre trying to do looks OK, but you have an HTML comment inside your javascript tag block thats probably breaking your script. remove `<!--Offices jquery -->`. And remember, you the javascript log/console is your friend.

Comment: I've tried removing that to no effect, I'm afraid... good idea, though.

Comment: @AdamCoulombe: Have you tried it? the line seems to make no difference: http://jsfiddle.net/G4afE/ PreventDefault seems to work as expected.